# Unable to remotely access apacheDS LDAP

Tags: apacheds

I am trying to set up ApacheDS LDAP on Windows 7.  It works fine when I try to access it locally (i.e. ldap://localhost:389/), but it fails when I try to access it from a remote server (ldap://192.168.xxx.xxx:389/).  It's not a firewall issue as far as I can tell, because when I bind an OpenLDAP instance to port 389 then I can access it fine.

Is there a configuration bit somewhere that I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the Client you must add in Hosts file and the correct parameters.